# Installing drush on Mac

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drush

I Want to install Drush on my MAC, I followed these steps: "https://www.drupal.org/node/1674222" only I got an error when I run "composer install" in the Drush directory.

I downloaded Drush from the Drush Github (https://github.com/drush-ops/drush)

The project is about to make a custom Drush command to export old Drupal project settings (.yml files) to a new project.

The error is something about there is no version set? I found this: "https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241431/how-do-i-resolve-this-installation-error" and I tried to downgrade the version but still the same error.

The error message:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for drush/drush No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) -> satisfiable by drush/drush[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - drupal/core 8.7.x-dev conflicts with drush/drush[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)].
    - Installation request for drupal/core 8.7.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.7.x-dev].
```

Comment: Did you try to install a specific version like in `composer global require drush/drush:9.*` ?

Comment: Yes, got the same error